# Fetch failing and crashing app but does not throw an error

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

Edit: I have found the culprit to be a unicode replacement character, '�', however I still am not sure how to handle this.

I have a bug in my app where using an umlaut character in the username field causes it to crash on login, however no error gets thrown and the app just crashes.

I've been unable to catch any error. I've tried using `try/catch` as well as `.catch`, but I'm still unable to get any indication as to what exactly is causing the problem.

I've identified which fetch is causing the problem, but have no way of debugging it and it never reaches `.then` or `.catch`.

What could be causing it to crash the entire app without throwing an error? Is there any type of response that can do this?

For what it's worth, here's the fetch:

Params:

```
{
    url: ...,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'Authorization': ...,
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: // some XML specific to the API
}
```

Original:

```
return fetch({ url, headers, method: 'POST', body: messageBody })
      .then(accountAuthDetailsResult => {
      // Unable to reach this point
```

Transpiled (if it makes any difference):

```
(0, _fetch2.default)({ url: url, headers: headers, method: 'POST', body: messageBody })
```

Comment: where's your `.catch`?

Comment: Just show all the code so we can see what's going wrong. The transpile shouldn't make a difference

Comment: Is `XML` set at value of `body` property a properly escaped and formatted string?

Comment: Special characters in a non utf-8 string will give any server php fits...can you utf8_encode() it?

Comment: Unless you are doing any encoding stuff yourself, a special character crashing the app sounds very much like a bug in the library. Make a reproducable example and report it to the maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

`url` should not be a property of `init` object, unless a `Request` object is passed as first parameter to `fetch()`. See [WorkerOrGlobalScope.fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters)

```
return fetch(url, {headers, method: 'POST', body: messageBody })
       .then(accountAuthDetailsResult => {})
```

or

```
let request = new Request(url, {headers, method: 'POST', body: messageBody });

return fetch(request).then(accountAuthDetailsResult => {})
```